# Get original (Case Sensitive) HTML with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, case-sensitive

Somewhere inside Original HTML text file:

```
<sPaN id="test"></sPaN>
```

In browser looks like this:

```
<span id="test"></span>
```

How can I get original html with cases preserved?

```
test['innerHTML'] //returns lower case.
```

**Edit:**

For those, curious why:
I'm using Syntax Highlighter to demonstrate some XML on page. And XML is a case sensitive language - so its important that demoed XML has original case. 
Syntax Highlighter outputs text using ['innerHTML'] property which returns tags in lowercase. so I need to patch the Syntax Highlighter.

Comment: I don't know the details about what the different browsers do here, but it's possible it can't be done at all. Why would one want this in the first place, though? What is your use case?

Comment: Who told you HTML is case-sensitive??!?

Comment: @Pekka웃 updated Original Post with my Use Case.

Comment: @Bondye, I did not make such statement. File served to client has cases preserved. That makes me hope there is a way to extract original case.

Comment: So you have XML in the HTML page? Shouldn't the XML be  text, as opposed to actual elements? (`&lt;sPaN&gt;....`)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Originally they are all XML. Then parsed with XSLT to become HTML. Making them text as you have suggested works, but makes large chunks unreadable in source code.

Comment: There may not be a way to do what you want. The XML is invariably going to be interpreted as HTML here, with the case being discarded (as it's correct for XML). Can't you add line breaks to the XML somehow, or use the existing line breaks, by working inside a `<pre>` element? (Although that'll probably not work with the syntax highlighter...)

Answer (score 0):

If you read HTML/XML from an input element the case is maintained.

i.e. your HTML could look like:

```
<textarea id="my-xml">
   <Example>
      <Node>Text</Node>
   </Example>
</textarea>
```

Then in your javascript/jQuery:

```
var myxml = $('#myxml-xml').val(); //my will have case sensitive XML
```